# eclipse not recognising jtwitter

Tags: android, eclipse, jtwitter

I am learning android. In my StatusActivity.java file , I am getting the below error :

```
Twitter twitter = new Twitter("username", "password");
```

[image]

I have imported the latest jtwitter jar `jtwitter-2.9.0.zip` and imported the same to project build path.

[image]

I am not sure why I am not getting an option to import the required class

Comment: Trying using `winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter twitter = new winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter("username", "password");`.

Comment: error : `winterwell cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: Are you using the jtwitter library or the modified version that comes with the yamba project. Is `jtwitter-2.9.0.zip - yamba` a zip file? If so, unzip it and extract `jtwitter.jar`. Add this jar using `Add External JARs`.

Comment: Mate that is resolved it. Can you post that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using a zipped file instead of `jtwitter jar`. This is why the jtwitter library classes aren't accessible.

Remove `jtwitter-2.9.0.zip - yamba` > Unzip this file > Extract `jtwitter.jar` > Add this jar to your project.

`winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter` should be available now.